# Insert data to Atlas MongoDB error appearing: Insert not permitted while document contains errors

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to insert data to a collection I created in Atlas MongoDB. The data is following:

```js
[
  { id: 1, performer: 'John Doe', genre: 'Rock', price: 25, day: 1, image: '/img/uploads/1fsd324fsdg.jpg' },
  { id: 2, performer: 'Rebekah Parker', genre: 'R&B', price: 25, day: 1, image: '/img/uploads/2f342s4fsdg.jpg' },
  { id: 3, performer: 'Maybell Haley', genre: 'Pop', price: 40, day: 1, image: '/img/uploads/hdfh42sd213.jpg' }
]
```

`I get the error : "Insert not permitted while document contains errors."

What am I doing wrong? Please advise.

Comment: How are you inserting?

Comment: using "insert document" option

Answer (score 4):

may be quote problem ...

use double quote to key and property

"id" : 1, "performer : "John Doe" .. ~

Answer (score 1):

replace with this

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "performer": "John Doe",
    "genre": "Rock",
    "price": 25,
    "day": 1,
    "image": "/img/uploads/1fsd324fsdg.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "performer": "Rebekah Parker",
    "genre": "R&B",
    "price": 25,
    "day": 1,
    "image": "/img/uploads/2f342s4fsdg.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "performer": "Maybell Haley",
    "genre": "Pop",
    "price": 40,
    "day": 1,
    "image": "/img/uploads/hdfh42sd213.jpg"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is reslved now, formatting was the problem.

Comment: Yes, please, explain what was wrong with the format. That would help.

Answer (score 0):

I do the following:
Modify **title** to **"title"** and mongo compass works.

Example:

```
[
  { "id": "1", "performer": "John Doe", "genre": "Rock", "price": "25", "day": "1", "image": "/img/uploads/1fsd324fsdg.jpg" },
]
```

Reference document: https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/documents/insert

Answer (score -1):

It's better that you use MongoDB Compass and connect to it with a connection string:

1. click on the connection
2. click on the connection using mongodb compass
3. then get the compass downloaded from MongoDB according to required OS
4. but use connection string of connection to MongoDB application

Once you connect to your Compass, you can use import data and then browse your file to use.